# Cloudflare flexible SSL for Red5

Tags: red5

I've been using Red5 server for some time now to host my flash Apps. but at this time, I am building a little app in **JS** (no AS3 this time) that uses the **Web Speech API**. It works wonderful, but every time a user wants to enter new input(voice), chrome will prompt them to allow or block microphone over and over again because my site is not connecting over **https**. To fix this I decided to resort to **CloudFlare's flexible SSL**. I've got a domain of my own and changed my nameservers so that it would work. The site is working through CloudFlare but I don't see any https. Do I need to open port 443? Do I have to change something on my server despite CloudFlare says one does not need a certificate for the flexible SSL?

I am using **Red5 1.0.5** and running it from my pc. My domain is active on CloudFlare. I can't connect to port 80 because of my ISP so I am using port 8080. I am also using CloudFlare DDNS updater.

Domain recodrs on CloudFlare

type: A, name: example.com, value: myDynamicIp(updated by DDNS updater)
Page Rule: http://www.example.com:8080/myAPP (I thought this would enable https by magic, don't ask me why). I tried the option to force https but then it would not connect and show me error 522.

As you can see I am new to DNS. I want to know how to create a self-signed cert too. I know all this should be very easy to do according to CloudFlare but I am confused.

**Note**: I am trying to implement https just because I want chrome to stop asking for permission for each input( or each time my app calls SpeechRecognition.start()) and not for security reasons.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

essentially the issue you describe where you are getting a 522 during an SSL connection (and not for HTTP) is likely due to the fact your SSL certificate is probably set as full or strict instead of flexible.

In order to set as flexible:

1. Go to your CloudFlare dashboard.
2. Click on the site, go to Crypto, in the SSL section make sure Flexible is selected.

For Free CloudFlare accounts SSL certificates can take up to 24 hours to verify; your site is good to go when you see the green "Active Certificate" label.